# ActionBarSherlock is not working in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I have an old eclipse project and I was using ActionBarSherlock library for customising action bar. Now I am migrating this project into android studio 3.0 but after including this library in project as a module , it says
**"Error:Execution failed for task ':thirdparty:actionbarsherlock:processDebugResources'.

> Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner'"**

Let me know how can I fix this issue or provide me any latest library or maven repository path for this library.

Thanks